# How to remove extra space in plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do you remove extra space in the graph? scale_y_continuous is also not working.

```
ggplot(data = data_div_1, aes(x = Initiative, y = Record, fill = Type)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 2, colour = 'gray50') +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(data_div_1$Initiative)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks_values, labels = abs(breaks_values)) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_economist_white(gray_bg = FALSE) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1A476F", "#2D6D66")) +
    labs(title = "Theme 1", x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "none") 

break_values
-15 -10  -5   0   5  10  15
```

I have to remake this diverging graph for seven subjects and all have similar outputs.

[image]

If `scale_x_discrete()` is removed shows correct fit but reversed labels.
[image]

```
dput(data_div_1)
structure(list(Theme = c("Theme 1", "Theme 1", "Theme 1", "Theme 1", 
"Theme 1", "Theme 1", "Theme 1", "Theme 1", "Theme 1", "Theme 1"
), Initiative = c("Initiative 1", "Initiative 2", "Initiative 3", 
"Initiative 4", "Initiative 5", "Initiative 1", "Initiative 2", 
"Initiative 3", "Initiative 4", "Initiative 5"), Type = c("Desirability", 
"Desirability", "Desirability", "Desirability", "Desirability", 
"Feasibility", "Feasibility", "Feasibility", "Feasibility", "Feasibility"
), Record = c(10, 9.5, 11, 11.5, 7.5, -9, -8.5, -9, -8.5, -8.5
), Label = c("Theme 1: Initiative 1", "Theme 1: Initiative 2", 
"Theme 1: Initiative 3", "Theme 1: Initiative 4", "Theme 1: Initiative 5", 
"Theme 1: Initiative 1", "Theme 1: Initiative 2", "Theme 1: Initiative 3", 
"Theme 1: Initiative 4", "Theme 1: Initiative 5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: If `Initiative` is a factor, try `?droplevels`, it seems that there are levels with no actual data, hence the blank spaces. As for the y axis limits, set `scale_y_continuous` argument `limits = range(break_values)`.

Comment: Autofit is resolve when I remove scale_x_discrete. How can I reverse the order of y-axis without distorting te plot, reversed when coord_flip()

Comment: Could you please provide working data example with `dput(data_div_1)`?

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved via `rev(unique(...))` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

breaks_values <- c(-15L, -10L, -5L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 15L)

ggplot(data = data_div_1, aes(x = Initiative, y = Record, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 2, colour = 'gray50') +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(unique(data_div_1$Initiative))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks_values, labels = abs(breaks_values)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_economist_white(gray_bg = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1A476F", "#2D6D66")) +
  labs(title = "Theme 1", x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]